Trying to run tasks in parallel but sync the total, cannot return Promise
I've been trying for a while but cannot figure it out. I'm trying to run a nodejs program that pings all device on the network and return the function. I have all the "pink" tasks running asyncronously but to grab the total result BEFORE returning the function.
async function pingAll(ips) {
  let promises = [];
  let pcs = [];

  ips.forEach(function (host) {
    promises.push(
      ping.promise
        .probe(host, {
          timeout: 3,
        })
        .then(function (res) {
          if (res.alive) {
            // removes duplicates such as wifi+ethernet
            return host;
            // console.log(host);
          }
          return null;
        })
    );
  });
  let values = await Promise.all(promises);
  console.log(values);
  console.log('outside');
  return values;
}

const online = pingAll(allIPs);

When I do a return, it outputs as a Promise {  } when I try to console.log the 'values' returned but 5 seconds later, the console.log outputs all of my IPs before the 'outside' print statement works. I just want this whole function to complete in its entirety before returning the IPs, any suggestions? I've probably logged almost 100 hours trying to figure this out.
I tried to do a ForEach for the array of IPs that append an object. And then the Promise.all should run them all asyncronously. But then it will not wait and return the IPs, it instead returns the value
Promise { <Pending> }

Can you explain better what you're expering and what you're getting back? Looking at your code there's nothing really that stands out to me as wrong.

Note that promises are not a mechanism for parallel processing at all. They're just a way to handle the result of operations that are asynchronous. So your pings will lick off immediately.

I just updated it, it returns the value of "Promise Pending" instead of the actual list of IPs. but then 5 seconds later, the console.log outputs the list I was expecting as its delayed. I just want my return statement to be a list of IPs instead of "Promise Pending"
If there's an alternative to Promise, please let me know

"I just want this whole function to complete in its entirety before returning the IPs" - this is not possible. You can however make it immediately return a promise for the IPS - which you did already! Your code works. You just need to use online.then(console.log), or await online, if you want to use the results from pingAll(allIPs).

If I try to do await before calling the function, I get the error "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"

@AndrewRendon use then , or wrap the pingAll call into its own async function or switch to ESM to support top-level await.

Sure, if you want to use await you need to put the call in an async function or a module. Where are you calling pingAll? And what do you want to do with the online variable? You haven't shown any of that code so we can't advise on that part without speculation.

I want to return that "online" variable to another program or file. await is suck a big deal because I want my script to wait entirely on the output of this before doing anything else, a callback will not be possible

Then just use ES modules. If you aren't using them, what are you using? But still, no, just return a promise to the rest of the program. Putting it in a .then() callback is possible.
